# expand to top html css

Tags: html, css

I am building an expand/collapse element. When the MORE INFO label/button is clicked, the content should expanded to-top instead of to-bottom.

Below you find my code.

And here are two screenshots. The first one shows the current behavior, the second one shows how it should look like when clicked, with the content above the MORE INFO label/button.

[image]

my expected result:
[image]

Would be great if you could help me resolve this issues. Thank you.

```css
.wrap-collabsible {
  margin-bottom: 1.2rem 0;
}

input[type='checkbox'] {
  display: none;
}

.lbl-toggle {
  display: block;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 1rem;
  color: #A77B0E;
  background: #FAE042;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 7px;
  /*   transition: all 0.25s ease-out; */
}

.collapsible-content {
  top: 0px;
  max-height: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  transform:
}

.toggle:checked+.lbl-toggle+.collapsible-content {
  max-height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<input id="collapsible" class="toggle" type="checkbox">
<label for="collapsible" class="lbl-toggle">More Info</label>
<div class="collapsible-content">
  <div class="content-inner">
    <p>
      QUnit is by calling one of the object that are embedded in JavaScript, and faster JavaScript program could also used with its elegant, well documented, and functional programming using JS, HTML pages Modernizr is a popular browsers without plug-ins. Test-Driven
      Development.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Codepen has totally different code

Comment: Oh, sorry, my mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Place the content right after the hidden checkbox
- Use this selector instead `.toggle:checked + .collapsible-content {`

```css
.wrap-collabsible {
  margin-bottom: 1.2rem 0;
}

input[type='checkbox'] {
  display: none;
}

.lbl-toggle {
  display: block;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 1rem;
  color: #A77B0E;
  background: #FAE042;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 7px;
}

.collapsible-content {
  top: 0px;
  max-height: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  transform:
}

.toggle:checked + .collapsible-content {
  max-height: 100vh;
}

.lbl-toggle:before {content: "More "}
.toggle:checked ~ .lbl-toggle:before {content: "Less "}
```

```html
<input id="collapsible" class="toggle" type="checkbox">
<div class="collapsible-content">
  <div class="content-inner">
    <p>
      QUnit is by calling one of the object that are embedded in JavaScript, and faster JavaScript program could also used with its elegant, well documented, and functional programming using JS, HTML pages Modernizr is a popular browsers without plug-ins. Test-Driven
      Development.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
<label for="collapsible" class="lbl-toggle">Info</label>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use flexbox and order the elements in the preferred order.

Wrap your HTML elements with a `div` and give the wrapper a `display: flex;` and make it appear in column direction with `flex-direction: column;`.

Then you simply reorder the elements with `order: 1` and `order: 2`.

```css
.collaps-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.wrap-collabsible {
  margin-bottom: 1.2rem 0;
}

input[type='checkbox'] {
  display: none;
}

.lbl-toggle {
  display: block;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 1rem;
  color: #A77B0E;
  background: #FAE042;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 7px;
  /*   transition: all 0.25s ease-out; */
  order: 2;
}

.collapsible-content {
  top: 0px;
  max-height: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  transform:
  order: 1;
}

.toggle:checked+.lbl-toggle+.collapsible-content {
  max-height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="collaps-wrapper">
  <input id="collapsible" class="toggle" type="checkbox">
  <label for="collapsible" class="lbl-toggle">More Info</label>
  <div class="collapsible-content">
    <div class="content-inner">
      <p>
        QUnit is by calling one of the object that are embedded in JavaScript, and faster JavaScript program could also used with its elegant, well documented, and functional programming using JS, HTML pages Modernizr is a popular browsers without plug-ins. Test-Driven
        Development.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```